# Search Function Carto VL

Tags: carto, search, carto-vl

I'm new to Carto VL and html, and could use some help. I'm currently building a map using Carto VL and want to implement a search feature that allows users to type in a location and have the map zoom to that location. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to search for any location or a location you have stored in a map dataset?

Comment: I want users to be able to search any location

Answer (score 0):

CARTO does not have an out of the box search box. On the one hand, you could build one using [Airship input component](https://carto.com/developers/airship/reference/#/styles/inputs) in combination of [CARTO's Data Services API](https://carto.com/developers/data-services-api/reference/#geocoding-functions) (you will need to work a lot if you select this option), or even better, a proper open source geocode. The result should be a geojson or geometry which [you can center and zoom in on it](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/). On the other, you can use [something already build such as Mapbox GL geocoder](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/).